# Manage String id sequence in spring boot entity

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, sequence

I'm working on oracle database to manage a JPA entity with a String Primary key.
I cannot modify the type on the PK to a Long or int in the database, so i want to know how to configure the pk sequence in my JPA entity, 
i've tried this :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_ID", sequenceName = "SEQ_ID" )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_ID")
@Column(name="SEQ_ID",unique=true, nullable = false,updatable = false)
private String id;
```

but when persisting a new entity i got the error : Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String
someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @GeneratedValue and @SequenceGenerator 
Also, a remark, @Id will automatically set `unique=true, nullable = false,updatable = false` so you can remove them from @Column.

Otherwise, you can check this article for more details about creating a custom string generator https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks, but if i do what you recommand, i have error ORA-01400: cant insert NULL in id

Comment: i removed both lines :                                      
 @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_ID", sequenceName = "SEQ_ID" )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_ID")

Comment: Okay after removing them, try adding in your entity code
 `@PrePersist 
    private void ensureId(){
    this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}`

But you have to handle generating same id exceptions. 

Otherwise, you can follow the tutorial mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write custom sequence String generator class and add that class as strategy for `@GenericGenerator` as below

```
public class foo implements IdentifierGenerator {

@Override
public Serilizable generate(SharedSessioContractImplementor session, Object object){
return session.createSQLQuery(select foo_seq_name.nextval from all_sequences where SEQUENCE_NAME='foo_seq_name').getSingleResult().toString;
}
```

Entity class should look like below:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="seq_id" strategy = "foo")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
private String foo_id;

}
```